# how can i order destinations based on a given destination country?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a destination id and I want to select other destinations, ordered first by the given destination's country followed by others. (preferably without using subquery)

```
destination:
- id
- name

destination_visa
- id_destination
- id_visa

visa
- id_visa
- country
```

How do I select the given destination's country and then order other destination based on this destination's country, preferably without using a subquery ?

**SQLFiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31503/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Is this what you had in mind?](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31503/7)

```
select
    d.id_destination, v.country, d.name 
from
    destination d
    inner join destination_visa dv on dv.id_destination = d.id_destination
    inner join visa v on dv.id_visa = v.id_visa
order by nullif (v.country, (select v2.country
                             from destination_visa dv2
                             inner join visa v2
                             on dv2.id_visa = v2.id_visa
                             where dv2.id_destination = 6));
```

There is still a subquery, which might be preselected into a variable.

I don't think a subquery should present a problem because it is not correlated to outer query, meaning it should be executed only once. As for order by, nulls are sorted first so I used that to nullify country matching given destination. Alternatively you might use this to make intend more clear:

```
order by case when v.country = (select v2.country
                                 from destination_visa dv2
                                 inner join visa v2
                                 on dv2.id_visa = v2.id_visa
                                 where dv2.id_destination = 6)
              then 0 -- Move matching country to front 
              else 1 -- Not a matching country
         end,
         v.country
```

Comment: Yes! Can you please explain the order by clause ? Also, can you talk a bit about the complexity of using a subquery in this way ?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the explanation, the other example helped me understand it. I have a question related to `nullif` though. nullif returns null if the condition is true. But what would `ORDER BY true` (or `false`, for that matter) do ?

Comment: I think I got it..when the countries match, null be returned which is equivalent to 0 (correct?), and hence move the matching country first. Correct ?

Comment: @brainydexter No, nullif will return first parameter if it is not equal to second one, and null if it is. Nulls are sorted first. Null and 0 are completely different animals.

Comment: `Nulls are sorted first` was the part of the missing puzzle that was messing me up. Thanks for the explanation and yes, thanks for reminding me null and 0 are different :)